# When does running command returns type error rather than CalledProcessError

Tags: python, python-2.7

Running "ifenslave bond-x interfacey" where interface-y is already a slave of bond-z by using subprocess.check_output  raises exception TypeError rather than CalledProcessError. I am not clear where this exception (TypeError) is coming from.

Comment: TypeError is a very generic one, and means that you supplied an unexpected type (e.g. int) to a function that was expecting a different one (e.g. str). Please provide the full traceback to properly root cause dthe issue.

Comment: If the source of the problem is a script you wrote, you might to also include a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)